# Relative frequencies / proportions with dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, frequency

Suppose I want to calculate the proportion of different values within each group. For example, using the `mtcars` data, how do I calculate the *relative* frequency of number of **gears** by **am** (automatic/manual) in one go with `dplyr`?

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- tbl_df(mtcars)

# count frequency
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

# am gear  n
#  0    3 15 
#  0    4  4 
#  1    4  8  
#  1    5  5
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
am gear  n rel.freq
 0    3 15      0.7894737
 0    4  4      0.2105263
 1    4  8      0.6153846
 1    5  5      0.3846154
```

Comment: Are those percentages the actual numbers you want? Where are they coming from, algebraically? Ah, 79% is 15/(15+4), 21% is 4/(15+4) and then for am==1 62% is 8/(8+5) etc. Got it.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, those are the number I want and Frank is correct,  they sum to 100% by the am variable (79+21) and (62+38)..

Comment: This really seems to be looking for a native dplyr implementation of `prop.table()`/`sweep()`. Also, in other questions some people are [asking for the option to include zero-counts for variables or variable-interactions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778195/using-dplyr-for-frequency-counts-of-interactions-must-include-zero-counts)

Answer (score 440, accepted):

Try this:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

#   am gear  n      freq
# 1  0    3 15 0.7894737
# 2  0    4  4 0.2105263
# 3  1    4  8 0.6153846
# 4  1    5  5 0.3846154
```

From the [**dplyr vignette**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html):

> When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping. That makes it easy to progressively roll-up a dataset.

Thus, after the `summarise`, the last grouping variable specified in `group_by`, 'gear', is peeled off. In the `mutate` step, the data is grouped by the remaining grouping variable(s), here 'am'. You may check grouping in each step with `groups`.

The outcome of the peeling is of course dependent of the order of the grouping variables in the `group_by` call. You may wish to do a subsequent `group_by(am)`, to make your code more explicit.

For rounding and prettification, please refer to the nice answer by @Tyler Rinker.

Comment: I just discovered that solution too, but I don't know why `sum(n)` works over the `am` group and not the `gear` group too...

Comment: See the [vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html): "When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping."

Comment: could also replace the `summarise(n = n())` line with `tally()` since it is a wrapper for that very statement.

Answer (score 53):

You can use `count()` function, which has however a different behaviour depending on the version of `dplyr`:

- dplyr 0.7.1: returns an *ungrouped* table: you need to group again by `am`
- dplyr < 0.7.1: returns a *grouped* table, so no need to group again, although you might want to `ungroup()` for later manipulations

**dplyr 0.7.1**

```
mtcars %>%
  count(am, gear) %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

**dplyr < 0.7.1**

```
mtcars %>%
  count(am, gear) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

This results into a **grouped table**, if you want to use it for further analysis, it might be useful to remove the *grouped* attribute with `ungroup()`.

Comment: This seems an invalid answer on `dplyr` 0.7.1. It does the frequency calculation overall on "gear", instead of within each level of "am".

Answer (score 35):

@Henrik's is better for usability as this will make the column character and no longer numeric but matches what you asked for...

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))

##   am gear  n rel.freq
## 1  0    3 15      79%
## 2  0    4  4      21%
## 3  1    4  8      62%
## 4  1    5  5      38%
```

**EDIT** Because Spacedman asked for it :-)

```
as.rel_freq <- function(x, rel_freq_col = "rel.freq", ...) {
    class(x) <- c("rel_freq", class(x))
    attributes(x)[["rel_freq_col"]] <- rel_freq_col
    x
}

print.rel_freq <- function(x, ...) {
    freq_col <- attributes(x)[["rel_freq_col"]]
    x[[freq_col]] <- paste0(round(100 * x[[freq_col]], 0), "%")   
    class(x) <- class(x)[!class(x)%in% "rel_freq"]
    print(x)
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
  as.rel_freq()

## Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
## Groups: am
## 
##   am gear  n rel.freq
## 1  0    3 15      79%
## 2  0    4  4      21%
## 3  1    4  8      62%
## 4  1    5  5      38%
```

Comment: You could always create an S3 "percentage" class with a `format` method that adds a percent sign... #overkill

Comment: Implementing this might be interesting too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100

Answer (score 19):

Despite the many answers, one more approach which uses `prop.table` in combination with 'dplyr' or 'data.table'.

Since 'dplyr' v. >= 1.1.0 we can use the `.by` argument in `mutate`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(freq = prop.table(n), .by = am)

#>   am gear  n      freq
#> 1  0    3 15 0.7894737
#> 2  0    4  4 0.2105263
#> 3  1    4  8 0.6153846
#> 4  1    5  5 0.3846154
```

Before 'dplyr' v. < 1.1.0 one approach would be:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  mutate(freq = prop.table(n))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am  gear     n  freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     0     3    15 0.789
#> 2     0     4     4 0.211
#> 3     1     4     8 0.615
#> 4     1     5     5 0.385
```

With 'data.table' we can do:

```r
library(data.table)
cars_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
cars_dt[, .(n = .N), keyby = .(am, gear)][, freq := prop.table(n), by = "am"][]

#>    am gear  n      freq
#> 1:  0    3 15 0.7894737
#> 2:  0    4  4 0.2105263
#> 3:  1    4  8 0.6153846
#> 4:  1    5  5 0.3846154
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness of this popular question, since version 1.0.0 of `dplyr`, parameter **.groups** controls the grouping structure of the `summarise` function after `group_by` [summarise help](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html).

With `.groups = "drop_last"`, `summarise` drops the last level of grouping. This was the only result obtained before version 1.0.0.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

original <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 0.1))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'am' (override with `.groups` argument)

original
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am  gear     n rel.freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>   
#> 1     0     3    15 78.9%   
#> 2     0     4     4 21.1%   
#> 3     1     4     8 61.5%   
#> 4     1     5     5 38.5%

new_drop_last <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 0.1))

dplyr::all_equal(original, new_drop_last)
#> [1] TRUE
```

With `.groups = "drop"`, all levels of grouping are dropped. The result is turned into an independent tibble with no trace of the previous `group_by`

```r
# .groups = "drop"
new_drop <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 0.1))

new_drop
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      am  gear     n rel.freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>   
#> 1     0     3    15 46.9%   
#> 2     0     4     4 12.5%   
#> 3     1     4     8 25.0%   
#> 4     1     5     5 15.6%
```

If `.groups = "keep"`, same grouping structure as .data (mtcars, in this case). `summarise` does not peel off any variable used in the `group_by`.

Finally, with `.groups = "rowwise"`, each row is it's own group. It is equivalent to "keep" in this situation

```r
# .groups = "keep"
new_keep <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n(), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 0.1))

new_keep
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   am, gear [4]
#>      am  gear     n rel.freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>   
#> 1     0     3    15 100.0%  
#> 2     0     4     4 100.0%  
#> 3     1     4     8 100.0%  
#> 4     1     5     5 100.0%

# .groups = "rowwise"
new_rowwise <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n(), .groups = "rowwise") %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 0.1))

dplyr::all_equal(new_keep, new_rowwise)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Another point that can be of interest is that sometimes, after applying `group_by` and `summarise`, a summary line can help.

```r
# create a subtotal line to help readability
subtotal_am <- mtcars %>%
  group_by (am) %>% 
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(gear = NA, rel.freq = 1)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

mtcars %>% group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(rel.freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(subtotal_am) %>%
  arrange(am, gear) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq =  scales::percent(rel.freq, accuracy = 0.1))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'am' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am  gear     n rel.freq
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>   
#> 1     0     3    15 78.9%   
#> 2     0     4     4 21.1%   
#> 3     0    NA    19 100.0%  
#> 4     1     4     8 61.5%   
#> 5     1     5     5 38.5%   
#> 6     1    NA    13 100.0%
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a small function for this repeating task:

```
count_pct <- function(df) {
  return(
    df %>%
      tally %>% 
      mutate(n_pct = 100*n/sum(n))
  )
}
```

I can then use it like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  count_pct
```

It returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl     n n_pct
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     4    11  34.4
2     6     7  21.9
3     8    14  43.8
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a general function implementing Henrik's solution on `dplyr` 0.7.1.

```
freq_table <- function(x, 
                       group_var, 
                       prop_var) {
  group_var <- enquo(group_var)
  prop_var  <- enquo(prop_var)
  x %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var, !!prop_var) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(freq = n /sum(n)) %>% 
    ungroup
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, try [`add_count()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html)  (to get around pesky group_by .groups).

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(am, gear) %>% 
  add_count(am, wt = n, name = "nn") %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n / nn)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R answer using `aggregate` and `ave` :

```
df1 <- with(mtcars, aggregate(list(n = mpg), list(am = am, gear = gear), length))
df1$prop <- with(df1, n/ave(n, am, FUN = sum))
#Also with prop.table
#df1$prop <- with(df1, ave(n, am, FUN = prop.table))
df1

#  am gear  n      prop
#1  0    3 15 0.7894737
#2  0    4  4 0.2105263
#3  1    4  8 0.6153846
#4  1    5  5 0.3846154
```

---

We can also use `prop.table` but the output displays differently.

```
prop.table(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear), 1)
   
#            3         4         5
#  0 0.7894737 0.2105263 0.0000000
#  1 0.0000000 0.6153846 0.3846154
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based upon Matifou's answer.

First I modified it to ensure that I don't get the freq column returned as a scientific notation column by using the scipen option.

Then I multiple the answer by 100 to get a percent rather than decimal to make the freq column easier to read as a percentage.

```
getOption("scipen") 
options("scipen"=10) 
mtcars %>%
count(am, gear) %>% 
mutate(freq = (n / sum(n)) * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple and idiomatic solution that respects prior grouping (computing proportions within each group and doesn't make you write any variable names twice (a common source of bugs!)

```r
props = function(data, ...) {
  data %>%
  count(...) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n), .keep="unused", by=...)
}
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,vs) %>% prop(gear, carb)
```

`prop` sums to one within each original group.

If you're not familiar with the [... syntax](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=...#fun-dot-dot-dot). It's incredibly useful for writing reusable functions.

Comment: That's right, I use = for assignment, and as far as I'm concerned anyone who doesn't is a luddite :P