# Proportional Tables by Group

Tags: r

I have a data.frame structured as follows:

```
location               gender        15.19     20.30      31.40      41.64      65.
New York                Female          2         41         13         19        1
New York                  Male          1         23         15         17        2
San Francisco           Female          1         27         14         14        3
San Francisco             Male          4         24         14         10        1
Mexico City             Female          1         40         26         11        3
Mexico City               Male          4         23         35          8        3
Paris                   Female          2         12         10          6        0
Paris                     Male          1         20         13         11        1
```

...and need to turn it into a proportion table with each cell representing its proportion of the two rows for its given city. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr) is one solution but is there an easier way to do it for multiple columns (and just transform them without making new columns?)

EDIT
Correct output would give each cell as a proportion of ALL cells within that city, so that all cells that share the location 'New York' would add up to 1, as would all cells that share location 'San Francisco', etc. i.e. :

```
 location             gender        15.19     20.30      31.40      41.64        65.
 New York             Female          .01       .31        .1         .14        .01
 New York               Male          .01       .17       .11         .13        .02
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library("data.table")
selected_cols <- colnames(df)[3:7]
setDT(df)[, prop.table(.SD), by = location, .SDcols = selected_cols]

#         location      X15.19    X20.30     X31.40     X41.64        X65.
# 1:      New York 0.014925373 0.3059701 0.09701493 0.14179104 0.007462687
# 2:      New York 0.007462687 0.1716418 0.11194030 0.12686567 0.014925373
# 3: San Francisco 0.008928571 0.2410714 0.12500000 0.12500000 0.026785714
# 4: San Francisco 0.035714286 0.2142857 0.12500000 0.08928571 0.008928571
# 5:   Mexico City 0.006493506 0.2597403 0.16883117 0.07142857 0.019480519
# 6:   Mexico City 0.025974026 0.1493506 0.22727273 0.05194805 0.019480519
# 7:         Paris 0.026315789 0.1578947 0.13157895 0.07894737 0.000000000
# 8:         Paris 0.013157895 0.2631579 0.17105263 0.14473684 0.013157895
```

**Verify results:** Whether each city sum to `1`

```
a1 <- setDT(df)[, prop.table(.SD), by = location, .SDcols = selected_cols]
sum(subset(a1, location == "New York", select = selected_cols))
# [1] 1
```

Then gender column can be combined with `a1`

```
do.call(cbind, list(gender = df$gender, a1))
```

**Data:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(location = c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco", 
"San Francisco", "Mexico City", "Mexico City", "Paris", "Paris"
), gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male"), X15.19 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), 
    X20.30 = c(41L, 23L, 27L, 24L, 40L, 23L, 12L, 20L), X31.40 = c(13L, 
    15L, 14L, 14L, 26L, 35L, 10L, 13L), X41.64 = c(19L, 17L, 
    14L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 11L), X65. = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("location", "gender", "X15.19", 
"X20.30", "X31.40", "X41.64", "X65."), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)
```

**EDIT:**
As per @Sumedh's suggestion in the comments below, gender column will not drop and all `selected_cols` has to be `double` type. This is due to proportions from `prop.table` being of `double` type. Else, `RHS = LHS data type coercion error` will arise when assignment by reference `:=` is performed on the `selected_cols`.

```
setDT(df)[, (selected_cols) := prop.table(.SD), by = location, .SDcols = selected_cols]
```

Comment: You can use this instead: `setDT(df)[, (selected_cols) := prop.table(.SD), 
          by = location, .SDcols = selected_cols]`