# mutate r conditional with data.frame as filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the probabilities for a very large data set of each id for one month and I came up here in the forum with the "mutate function" however it does not really work the way i want. My data looks similar to that and I want to calculate the column P.:

```
ID Month Day       E  P
1 200701 20070101 .3 .333
1 200701 20070102 .5 .333
1 200701 20070105 .5 .333
1 200702 20070106 .6 1
2 200701 20070101 .4 .5
2 200701 20070103 .3 .5
```

For my trials I have subsetted the ID and Month and then simply used 1/length(df$Month). 
My idea now was to extract all IDs:

```
u <- subset(df, !duplicated(df$ID))
s <- subset(df, !duplicated(df$Month)) #Month is defined as date variable
```

and then mutate them with a formular similar to that:

```
mutate(df, p =  1/length(df$ID == u & df$month ==s))
```

This does not work unfortunatly.

Or do I have to do a loop?

Comment: Please, show your desired output.

Comment: So this `df %>% group_by(ID, Month) %>% mutate(P = 1/n())`

Comment: Using only `base R`, `df$P <- with(df, 1/ave(seq_along(ID), ID, Month, FUN = length))`

Comment: Almost a dupe of this probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, P := (1/.N) ,by = c("ID","Month")]
# > dt
#   ID  Month      Day   E         P
#1:  1 200701 20070101 0.3 0.3333333
#2:  1 200701 20070102 0.5 0.3333333
#3:  1 200701 20070105 0.5 0.3333333
#4:  1 200702 20070106 0.6 1.0000000
#5:  2 200701 20070101 0.4 0.5000000
#6:  2 200701 20070103 0.3 0.5000000
```

using dplyr : @Sotos has also wrote this answer. and he wrote it first

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(ID,Month) %>% 
  mutate(1/n())

#     ID  Month      Day     E     1/n()
#  (int)  (int)    (int) (dbl)     (dbl)
#1     1 200701 20070101   0.3 0.3333333
#2     1 200701 20070102   0.5 0.3333333
#3     1 200701 20070105   0.5 0.3333333
#4     1 200702 20070106   0.6 1.0000000
#5     2 200701 20070101   0.4 0.5000000
#6     2 200701 20070103   0.3 0.5000000
```

Comment: @Sotos I want to assure you that you wrote this  first , but even i had this in mind...i seriously didn't copy.. actually i learn n() yesterday here itself..

Comment: No worries. I believe you :)