# r dplyr summarize and spread : Calculate % of row (Like Excel PivotTable)

Tags: r

I'm a new R programmer with what is probably a very simple issue.

I have a dplyr summarize/spread snippet as follows:

```
enroll_data_eth_sum <- group_by(enroll_data_distinct, EMISEthnicity) %>% 
  summarize(freq = n()
  ) %>% 
  spread(EMISEthnicity, freq)
```

Which produces this table:

[image: Output Table]

What I need is that table to be percentages of the row...not the values.  I have tried a few things (like freq = (n=n()) / sum(n)), but this just gave all 1s (which upon reflection was probably correct).

Any thoughts?  I know it's something simple...thank you!!

John

UPDATE:  I tried the following based on Cedric's post:

```
enroll_data_eth_sum <- group_by(enroll_data_distinct, EMISEthnicity) 
 %>% 
 summarize(n = n()) %>% 
 mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>% 
 spread(EMISEthnicity, freq)
```

But that gave me this table:

[image: Updated with Mutate]

The values are correct...but I need it all on one row.  ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative frequencies / proportions with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr)

Comment: Hi Cedric, I tried that...but that mtcars code gave me 7 rows (one for each summary total of Ethnicity) and 8 columns (one for each Ethnicity).  I just need it all on one row...like the Excel "% of Row" calculation.

Comment: Sorry, it's good you got the right answer then !

Comment: @JohnLaPlante if gatsky's answer helped, consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the n column, eg:

```
enroll_data_eth_sum <- group_by(enroll_data_distinct, EMISEthnicity) %>% 
 summarize(n = n()) %>% 
 mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
 select(-n) %>%
 spread(EMISEthnicity, freq)
```

Comment: Perfect!!  That's it.   Thank you so much!!