# Cannot access data from tbl df object to be used on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lda, topic-modeling, tbl

I'm working on a set of LDA models to compare their predictive accuracy on topic assignments. Some short description below.

I applied the per document per topic assignment extracting the topic with the highest "gamma" (15 in total) for each document, I then used Chang and Blei's (2009) `rtm` method to get topic prediction per document per word/token and select the most frequent topic in a given document as the predicted topic for that document. Finally, I merged both predictions together with `topic` as the header for the first method `consensus` as the second method, matched by document `ID` and keeping the original document text. The data (named `assignments`) can be assessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hfhmvn0mp31uge/assignments.Rdata?dl=0) (330 x 6, not very large).

I tried to visualize the predictive accuracy of the methods with `ggplot2`, using the per document/per topic method as the baseline plotted along the y-axis and the `rtm` method evaluated on the x-axis with the following code

```html
library(foreign)
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lda)
library(igraph)
library(scales)

load("~/assignments.Rdata")

assignments %>%
  count(topic, consensus, wt_var = freq) %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(consensus, topic, fill = percent)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "red", label = percent_format()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "RTM assignments",
       y = "Documents came from",
       fill = "% of assignments")
```

However, I received an error message at the `count(topic, consensus,...)` line, showing `Error in count(., topic, consensus, wt_var = freq) : unused argument (consensus)`, yet, if I removed `consensus` from the line of code, I got `Error in count(., topic, wt_var = freq) : object 'topic' not found`
.
I suspect this could be an S4 class issue (or maybe not), so I tried the following methods. Using `""` on `group_by()` variable, but it didn't work. Instead, I got this error message `Error in sum(n) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument`.

Then I used `tbl_df(assignments)` to convert `assignments` to tibble compatible object. Again, it didn't work, R still could not find `consensus` and `topic` data from the tibble object.

I am really confused and would like to have someone take a look at my code and enlighten me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: `plyr` has a count function that will clash with the count function from dplyr. If you need to load both (unlikely) you need to load them in the correct order

Comment: I need `plyr` for `percent_format()` in the `ggplot` code block. So should I first load `plyr` prior to `dplyr`?

Comment: if it is only for one function I would use `plyr::percent_format()`

Comment: Oops, `percent_format()` is in `scales` package, not `plyr`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having issues with your data manipulation in the first half of the function. I grouped the assignments first by topic and consensus so the count would differentiate between them (rather than just returning a sum of frequencies), then applied count (with the variables in quotes) and finally mutate:

```
library(dplyr)

assignments_2 <- assignments %>% group_by(topic, consensus) %>%
    count(vars = "topic", wt_var = "freq") %>%
    mutate(percent = n / sum(n))
```

If that puts the data into the format I think you want it, you should then be able to plot your graph!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it still returns the same error message after re-ran the `ggplot` code: `Error in sum(n) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument`. The error appears between the `count()` and `mutate()` lines, there must be some sequencing issues there that I haven't figure out.

Comment: Sorry, I put the pipes in the wrong place (still pretty new to R). The data manip. works for me fine, although I've just noticed the `count()` drops the document variable which you want to use in the `ggplot` - I'm not sure how to fix that without knowing exactly what you're trying to pull out of the tibble.

Comment: Hi, mine still didn't work. The strange thing is, if I used quotation marks `""` on `count` variables, `count()` and `mutate()` will generate the data format I want, but it wouldn't fit `ggplot` as it will return an error message `invalid 'type' (closure) of argument`. This indicates some objects have been transformed into "function" without me knowing, I guess.

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr), but none of the methods are valid, at least for my data, seems that `dplyr` has somehow changed some of the codes.

Comment: Try separating your code into different functions rather than piping everything, that should at least fix your closure error. As for the ggplot, I got these errors: `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Column `y` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list` - I don't really understand what you're trying to plot so I'm not sure I can help with that?

Comment: I was finally able to get the code to work after I 1) added `library(scales)` (in order to use `percent_format()` in the `ggplot`) and 2) replace `title` with `topic` in the `ggplot` function and, most importantly, 3) relaunch my Rstudio again. Thanks again for helping on this.