# Percentages over Multiple Columns with two Factors

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to get relative proportions of tallies that belong to two seperate categories. This is an example of the raw file.

```
A tibble: 8 x 5
  resp          euRefVoteW1 euRefVoteW2 euRefVoteW3 Paper    
  <fct>               <int>       <int>       <int> <fct>    
1 Remain                316         290         313 Times    
2 Leave                 157         123         159 Times    
3 Will Not Vote           2           3           3 Times    
4 Don't Know             56          51          55 Times    
5 Remain                190         175         199 Telegraph
6 Leave                 339         282         334 Telegraph
7 Will Not Vote           4           3           4 Telegraph
8 Don't Know             70          62          69 Telegraph
```

It is a tally of two different factors. I'm trying to convert the tally of responses into percentages so it would look something like this:

```
A tibble: 8 x 5
  resp          euRefVoteW1 euRefVoteW2 euRefVoteW3 Paper    
1 Remain                52%         53%        .. Times    
2 Leave                 43%         42%         .. Times    
3 Will Not Vote          1%            2%       . Times    
4 Don't Know             4%            3%       . Times    
5 Remain                35%         35%         . Telegraph
6 Leave                 52%         52%         . Telegraph
7 Will Not Vote          2%           2%           . Telegraph
8 Don't Know             11%          11%          . Telegraph
```

(Obviously these numbers aren't correct, but I hope it shows that each 4 x 1 section should sum to 100%).

The dataframe is in a similar format to table already, so is there a way to apply the prop.table method to the df ? When I tried like this, it refuses as the df is not a clean array. Is there a way around this?

```
for_stack <- combined_tallies %>%
               group_by(Paper, resp) %>%
                prop.table(margin=2)
```

[Here is an rds copy of the dataframe if this helps!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dij3fq0gf1jcyaa/combined_tallies.rds?dl=0)

[The best answers I could find elsewhere here in SO were of no use] ([Percentage of factor levels by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953231/percentage-of-factor-levels-by-group-in-r))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you are looking for it

```
library(tidyverse)
combined_tallies %>% 
  group_by(Paper) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x / sum(.x, na.rm = T) * 100))

# A tibble: 20 x 10
# Groups:   Paper [5]
resp  euRefVoteW1 euRefVoteW2 euRefVoteW3 euRefVoteW4 euRefVoteW6 euRefVoteW7 euRefVoteW8
   <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Rema~      59.5        62.1        59.1        61.0        63.7        60.3        61.2  
 2 Leave      29.6        26.3        30          29.0        25.2        35.6        35.2  
 3 Will~       0.377       0.642       0.566       0.565       0.377       0.377       0.377
 4 Don'~      10.5        10.9        10.4         9.42       10.7         3.77        3.20 
...
```

Comment: This perfectly does what I was asking but would you mind explaining how ? I understand the `mutate(across(where(is.numeric, ` verb part, but don't understand what the ` ~ .x ` sign denotes. The ` x/sum(.x, etc.. ` is just the percentage formula : does the `~x` just denote a  general term ?

Comment: `across()` makes it easy to the same transformation to multiple columns.
See vignette("colwise") for more details. Instead of .x columns are substituted for which you want to calculate percentages. `~` this is the beginning of the calculation formula. See ?`~`.

Answer (score 3):

I have recreated your data set using `dput()`, which you are encouranged to use to provide reproducible data for answers on StackOverflow.

```
votes <- structure(list(resp = c("Remain", "Leave", "Will Not Vote", "Don’t Know", 
"Remain", "Leave", "Will Not Vote", "Don’t Know"), ref1 = c(316, 
157, 2, 56, 190, 339, 4, 70), ref2 = c(290, 123, 3, 51, 175, 
282, 3, 62), ref3 = c(313, 159, 3, 55, 199, 334, 4, 69), paper = c("Times", 
"Times", "Times", "Times", "Telegraph", "Telegraph", "Telegraph", 
"Telegraph")), .Names = c("resp", "ref1", "ref2", "ref3", "paper"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

An alternative approach is to change the structure of your dataset ahead of performing your analysis. You are trying to create relative values not across entire columns or rows but for subsets. One way around this is to use the `tidyverse` package and perform your analysis in that format. You can always revert to the original structure once you have calculated percentages.

```
library(tidyverse)
vote_long <- votes %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(ref1, ref2, ref3), names_to = "ref", values_to = "votes")
```

```
vote_long

# A tibble: 24 x 4
   resp          paper ref   votes
   <chr>         <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 Remain        Times ref1    316
 2 Remain        Times ref2    290
 3 Remain        Times ref3    313
 4 Leave         Times ref1    157
 5 Leave         Times ref2    123
 6 Leave         Times ref3    159
 7 Will Not Vote Times ref1      2
 8 Will Not Vote Times ref2      3
 9 Will Not Vote Times ref3      3
10 Don’t Know    Times ref1     56
# … with 14 more rows
```

```
# created grouped relative values 

vote_long_relative <- vote_long %>% 
  group_by(paper, ref) %>% 
  mutate(rel_votes = votes/sum(votes) * 100)

vote_wide_relative <- vote_long_relative %>% 
  select(-votes) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(resp, paper), names_from = "ref", values_from = "rel_votes")

vote_wide_relative
```

```
# Groups:   paper [2]
  resp          paper       ref1   ref2   ref3
  <chr>         <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Remain        Times     59.5   62.1   59.1  
2 Leave         Times     29.6   26.3   30    
3 Will Not Vote Times      0.377  0.642  0.566
4 Don’t Know    Times     10.5   10.9   10.4  
5 Remain        Telegraph 31.5   33.5   32.8  
6 Leave         Telegraph 56.2   54.0   55.1  
7 Will Not Vote Telegraph  0.663  0.575  0.660
8 Don’t Know    Telegraph 11.6   11.9   11.4
```